# CSS Hover Flipper Not Working

Tags: html, css, hover, transform, flipper

Creating a div based flipper. The front and back are currently coded as colours but the back will eventually be a background-image.

I've followed this guide here: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip which doesn't work yet works in the demo. I've presumably done something wrong.

Heres the

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container">

    <div class="flipper">

        <div class="front">

            Front

        </div>

        <div class="back">

            Back

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-container {
    perspective:1000;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
     height:480px;width:320px;
}

.flipper {
    position:relative;
}

.front {
    background:#99CCFF;
    z-index:2;
}

.back {
    background:#CCC;
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.front, .back {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
}
```

and a lovely jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ssp7L/

Answer (score 0):

What browser did you use? If you use Chrome v35, you need to add prefix to transform property.

```
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective:1000;
}

    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    height:480px;width:320px;
}

.flipper {
    position:relative;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.front {
    background:#99CCFF;
    z-index:2;
}

.back {
    background:#CCC;
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ssp7L/2/)